# Find the Delphi source line that matches an offset in a DLL

Tags: java, delphi, debugging, assembly, java-native-interface

I am trying to find the cause of a crash in my Java application. It is actually a crash of the JVM, caused by a call to a native library through JNI.

Here is what I can see in the generated `hs_err_pidxxxx.log` :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO (0xc0000094) at pc=0x4fa19409, pid=1456, tid=4068
#
# JRE version: 6.0_30-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [JCustomOpc.dll+0x9409]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x4ab1c400):  JavaThread "opc_service" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4068, stack(0x4f200000,0x4f250000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000094

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x4f24f958, EDX=0x80000000
ESP=0x4f24f93c, EBP=0x4f24f940, ESI=0x4f24f9a4, EDI=0x52d396f4
EIP=0x4fa19409, EFLAGS=0x00010286

Top of Stack: (sp=0x4f24f93c)
0x4f24f93c:   4f24f98a 4f24f970 4fa1968a 52220000
0x4f24f94c:   5042f418 4f24f9a4 4b1ba6e8 00000004
0x4f24f95c:   52d396f4 4ab1c528 4f24f9a8 4f24f9a6
0x4f24f96c:   4f24f9a4 4f24f98c 4fa197cc 4f24f98a
0x4f24f97c:   52220000 5042f418 00000036 4f24f9a8
0x4f24f98c:   4ab33d1c 4fa6388f 52220000 5042f418
0x4f24f99c:   4ab1c528 4ab33d24 00000008 6d92f61f
0x4f24f9ac:   4ab1c528 4ab33d1c 00000022 0000000a 

Instructions: (pc=0x4fa19409)
0x4fa193e9:   db 89 c1 dd 45 08 d8 8b 88 21 a7 4f 83 ec 08 df
0x4fa193f9:   3c 24 9b 58 5a 09 d2 79 11 f7 da f7 d8 83 da 00
0x4fa19409:   f7 b3 8c 21 a7 4f f7 d8 eb 06 f7 b3 8c 21 a7 4f
0x4fa19419:   05 5a 95 0a 00 89 11 89 41 04 5b 5d c2 08 00 55 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x4f24f958 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4ab1c400
EDX=0x80000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x4f24f93c is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4ab1c400
EBP=0x4f24f940 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4ab1c400
ESI=0x4f24f9a4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4ab1c400
EDI=0x52d396f4 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x4f200000,0x4f250000],  sp=0x4f24f93c,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [JCustomOpc.dll+0x9409]
C  [JCustomOpc.dll+0x968a]
C  [JCustomOpc.dll+0x97cc]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  javafish.clients.opc.JOpc.getDownloadGroupNative()Ljavafish/clients/opc/component/OpcGroup;
J  fr.def.iss.vd2.mod_opc_service.JEasyFacade.getPossiblyChangedGroups()Ljava/util/Collection;
J  fr.def.iss.vd2.mod_opc_service.OpcServiceImpl.updateState()V
j  fr.def.iss.vd2.mod_opc_service.OpcServiceImpl.access$3000(Lfr/def/iss/vd2/mod_opc_service/OpcServiceImpl;)V+1
j  fr.def.iss.vd2.mod_opc_service.OpcServiceImpl$5.handlOpcEvents()V+103
j  fr.def.iss.vd2.mod_opc_service.OpcServiceImpl$Worker.run()V+156
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

So, it shows that there is a division by zero in `JCustomOpc.dll`. `JCustomOpc.dll` is a third party library, written in Delphi, and compiled by our team with Borland Delphi pro 7.0. What I am trying to do now, is to find where in the Delphi source code this division by zero happens.

I am mainly a Java programmer, and I am not comfortable debugging native code. So, I followed a [tutorial on JVM crash analysis](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html).

I followed the instructions :

```
> dumpbin /headers JCustomOpc.dll
...
OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             10B magic #
            2.25 linker version
           60800 size of code
           12400 size of initialized data
               0 size of uninitialized data
           616A8 RVA of entry point
            1000 base of code
           62000 base of data
          400000 image base
...
```

So, the image base is 400000, and according to the tutorial I expect the division instruction to be at offset 409409.

Let's look at it with the disassembler :

```
> dumpbin /exports /disasm JCustomOpc.dll
  ...
  004093E0: C3                 ret
  004093E1: 8D 40 00           lea         eax,[eax]
  004093E4: 55                 push        ebp
  004093E5: 8B EC              mov         ebp,esp
  004093E7: 53                 push        ebx
  004093E8: 31 DB              xor         ebx,ebx
  004093EA: 89 C1              mov         ecx,eax
  004093EC: DD 45 08           fld         qword ptr [ebp+8]
  004093EF: D8 8B 88 21 46 00  fmul        dword ptr [ebx+00462188h]
  004093F5: 83 EC 08           sub         esp,8
  004093F8: DF 3C 24           fistp       qword ptr [esp]
  004093FB: 9B                 wait
  004093FC: 58                 pop         eax
  004093FD: 5A                 pop         edx
  004093FE: 09 D2              or          edx,edx
  00409400: 79 11              jns         00409413
  00409402: F7 DA              neg         edx
  00409404: F7 D8              neg         eax
  00409406: 83 DA 00           sbb         edx,0
  00409409: F7 B3 8C 21 46 00  div         eax,dword ptr [ebx+0046218Ch]
  0040940F: F7 D8              neg         eax
  00409411: EB 06              jmp         00409419
  00409413: F7 B3 8C 21 46 00  div         eax,dword ptr [ebx+0046218Ch]
  00409419: 05 5A 95 0A 00     add         eax,0A955Ah
  0040941E: 89 11              mov         dword ptr [ecx],edx
  00409420: 89 41 04           mov         dword ptr [ecx+4],eax
  00409423: 5B                 pop         ebx
  00409424: 5D                 pop         ebp
  00409425: C2 08 00           ret         8
  ...
```

409409 is indeed a div instruction.

I know very few about assembly, but this code seems to manipulate a floating point value and make an integer division. I searched the Delphi source code, but found nothing that looks like an arithmetic operation.

I am pretty sure there is a reliable way of finding which Delphi function matches this piece of assembly, but I don't know how to do that. I have the whole source code of this dll, and I have full control on how to compile it.

The delphi sources (.pas) generate compiled files (.dcu), maybe these files could help for my problem, but I don't know what to do with them. There is an option of the linker, to create a map file. It does create a JCustomOpc.map file, which is a text file containing a lots of symbols and offsets. But the offsets don't match anything near 9404.

I must add that this crash happens on the machine of our customer, but is not reproductible on our machines. Also, it is not really possible to do some tests on the customer's machine, so I'm kind of stuck with working from the `hs_err_pid file` only.

What can I do now in order to find where the problematic source line is ?

### Edit

Here is the [generated detailed map file](http://pastebin.com/86BgGyMM).

Comment: You have to know DLL load address to map an address of interest to the VA in the image.

Comment: I would add the Jedi JCL Debug stuff or MadExcept to your dll, do a big try-catch block around EVERY one of your exported DLL functions, and dump an exception log including a whole stack trace. You definitely shouldn't be allowing Access violations or exceptions to get raised back into the app hosting the DLL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to build the DLL and output a detailed map file. The settings in the linker options control map file output. That map file will give you the start address of every function in your DLL and it should be easy enough to work it out from there.

Another option, if you can reproduce the error on a dev machine with Delphi installed, is to simply debug the DLL with the Delphi debugger. This will break when the exception is raised and you will have even more information than just the identity of the troublesome function.

Comment: I generated the detailed map file (see the edit in my post), but I am unable to find an offset near 9409.

Comment: Most likely then that is some library code that the .DLL links with. You did choose a Detailed map file, and compiled with all debug information in.  I think you'd be better off to focus on getting a stack-traceback and forget about locating this single binary address, even if it worked, you're missing most of the call-stack context you need to find the problem.

Comment: Look in the section titled "Publics by Value". They are listed in address order. For an exe you need to subtract 0x1000 from the reported offset to get the value matching that in the map file. I can't remember but you may or may not need to do the same with a DLL. And remember that when you rebuild with a detailed map you now have a different DLL. So the exception may occur at a different address in this new DLL.

Comment: OK, I believe you will need to subtract 0x1000 and so in the example here you are looking for 0x8409. However, you have a new DLL now and so you must make sure that you find out the address at which the exception is raised for the new DLL.

Comment: And one more thing. Really make sure that your DLL is coded to catch all exceptions. You mustn't let them propagate beyond the module boundary. Very bad form. Go and wag your finger at your Delphi dev colleagues.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for all those directions. The start of the function should be 93e4, and the corresponding symbol name in the map file (for 83e4) is DateTimeToTimeStamp. This is an important hint, now I can focus on code that handles times or dates.

Comment: I continued to search the correspondance between the `call` instructions in the asm and the mapping in the "public by values" section, and I was able to reconstruct the full stacktrace ! Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Hi! I tested similar things with my Delphi exe by causing an AV in a certain line and comparing the MAP file and the exception address, and found out the offset in my case to be not 0x1000 but 0x100E. The Image Base is the default 400000. I'm using Delphi XE2, so am just wondering could this offset have changed or is there some other reason? Also letting know that it seems that the offset to subtract maybe can also be 0x100E.

Answer (score 4):

You can load your dll project in delphi, then in the *Run/Parameters* menu you define your java appli as host. Then you press F9. When the bug trigs then the delphi IDE should highlight the problematic source code line. Dont forget to make this in debug mode and maybe with "Use debug DCU" checked in case of it would happend in the RTL.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler optimizations are going to give you some trouble mapping the assembly directly to the Pascal source in Delphi, as it's unlikely there's a 'truly' simple correlation.  However, if the dll is produced in-house, you may be able to have the source team create one with debug information/symbols built in.  That ought to allow you to attach a debugger and provide more human-acceptable diagnostics.  But it's still likely to be a tough slog.

Comment: Agreed. Although the OP is asking for "How do I do this with a MAP file", I have always found that the actual runtime address of a DLL (which could get relocated) and correlating that to a MAP file, is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @WarrenP You can always find out where the DLL did get loaded. And you can invariably choose a base address to avoid relocation.

Comment: @Michael It's trivial to produce a map file for a DLL that identifies where each function starts. Your other point is a good one. Just build with debug info and debug from the Delphi IDE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Admittedly there's some conjecture as it applies to delphi particularly. Though I've seen some surprising things with regards to optimizations when trying to do similar things back in my C++ Builder days ;)

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. If you have a detailed map and the actual base address then you are good to go.